# ActiveDirectory - Secondary Owner

Tags: c#, security, active-directory, directoryentry, active-directory-group

I would like to pull out the primary and secondary owners of a group in AD, however, I can not seem to find any way to pull out the **secondary** owner.  Primary owner can be extracted using the code below.

I have gone through all of the items in directory entry properties, which does not seem to contain the secondary owner.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
    private static string GetGroupOwner(string groupName)
    {
        string owner = null;
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
        if (group != null)
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry= (DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject();
            var propertyValueCollection = (System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection)entry.Properties["managedBy"];
            owner = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, propertyValueCollection.Value.ToString()).ToString();
        }

        return owner;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So far as I am aware Secondary Owners are available only as part of ActiveRoles Server:

http://www.quest.com/activeroles-server/

There is detailed documentation and tools avaialable for interacting with this server.

The secondary owners (of which there can be more than one) are held in the edsvaSecondaryOwners attribute:

http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/New-QADGroup

Comment: Thanks Ashigore.  Does this mean that I require ActiveRoles installed on the machine where the command is run?  I don't think this is an option for us.  Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Apologies for my lack of understanding with this, I am not too familiar with the AD / ARS world.  I would imagine though that since they are both through LDAP calls to AD, I could get it through some other mechanism already provided through the LDAP interfaces in c#?  Please let me know if I am barking up the wrong tree.